# C++ CreateFile does not found .txt file in same folder as .exe

Tags: c++, winapi, createfile

I'm trying to use `CreateFile` function, but it does not go as planned.

I did a simple test code :

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    HANDLE hFile;
    hFile = CreateFile(_T("test.txt"), GENERIC_READ, NULL, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, NULL, NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        cout << GetLastError() << endl;
        Sleep(2000);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I generate the `.exe` and place a file `test.txt` in the same folder.

When I execute the `.exe` I get `getLastError() = 2` which means `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

How is it even possible?

Comment: If this is in Visual Studio the default folder (unless you changed the `Working Directory` setting in debug settings) is not the same as the executable. It will be same folder as the project.

Comment: Hello, I launch the .exe myself by double clicking on it in the folder "Release".

Comment: Maybe your file has two .txt extensions. Windows adds confusion by hiding extensions. You may actually have `test.txt.txt` when you wanted `test.txt`

Comment: I dont know if i am stupid or you are a genius, but thank you this is the exact problem...

Comment: Please learn about a programs *current working directory* (`getcwd()` is useful) and how to change it (`chdir()` for example).

Comment: My advice is to disable the "Hide Extensions for known types" in your view settings for explorer. This is one of the first things I always do when setting up a new windows box.

Comment: ***if i am stupid or you are a genius, but thank you this is the exact problem*** This is a reasonably common issue here. I have seen it dozens of times.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: The only thing you need to know about the current working directory is to not ever use it. As a per-process property it is unreliable, and generally not under your control.

Comment: @IInspectable it's completely reliable if your program makes sure to always change it to what it needs to be as its first order of business.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: How do you control a per-process property in a multi-threaded environment, where you don't even control creation of all threads?

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Or the fact that some system APIs, like dialogs, also can change the CWD.  Best to NEVER rely on relative paths, ALWAYS use absolute paths.

Comment: @IInspectable who said anything about the program being multithreaded?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: sure CWD can change, but that's checkable. In any case, I (personally) prefer to always use paths relative to the location of my executable.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Then you are not actually using *true* relative paths (paths relative to the CWD, as demonstrated in the OP's question), you are actually using absolute paths that just *happen* to use the EXE path as their prefix.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I know. That bit was not meant to be in relation to OPs question - just me stating my personal preference.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Always expect an application on Windows to be multi-threaded. The OS will create threads, and you have no control over this. Again, you cannot reliably use the current working directory in a Windows application. And there is no reason to rely on it either. If you believe otherwise, please provide a convincing use-case, for which there is no other solution.